# php string to array conversion without using eval

Tags: php, arrays

Is there any option to convert string to array without using danger `eval`?

I don't want a solution using `eval` like below

```
eval("\$a=array(1,2,3,4);");
print_r($a);
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
)
```

For example I have a string like below

```
$my_string_form='array( 
                            "col1"=>"name", 
                            "input"=>array(),
                            "parameters"=>array( 
                                               "default"=>"xyz",
                                               "other"=>array(),
                                               "something"=>new stdClass() 
                                               )
                      )
                 ';
```

I would like to validate whether its defined properly or not, if defined properly I would like to access array elements one by one

```
if($real_array=somelogic_to_validate($my_string_form))
{
       // Valid array fine, do some work on it
       foreach($real_array as $key =>$v)
       {

       }
}else
{
          die("Bad string received");
}
```

Comment: Could you describe how you obtain the array-as-string $my_string_form in the first place? Maybe there is a way to get a better formatting for this array, for example in JSON. Generally it's a bad idea to treat arrays like this and there is almost always a better way, let's find it :)

Comment: Unfortunately, for some reason, `$my_string_form` I can't have json, I know if it was there I would have done `json_decode($my_string_form,true)`, so looking for some kind of parser

Comment: PHP is a parser and it's implementation is `eval`.  You don't have to `eval` the string directly.  `eval("\$s = serialize($my_string_form);"); $a = unserialize($s);`